# Losing names when unnesting a JSON in R using purrr::map (unlist, t, as_tibble)

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

Apologies for the large-ish initial data share but it helps as it will make the problem reproducible. I have a large-ish JSON of basketball play by play data in R, that I'd like to flatten into a dataframe. Here's the first 6 items in the JSON as a list in R:

```
my.pbp.data = list(structure(list(id = "0e2d8178-dfb7-4159-953e-f1851a27aee8", 
    clock = "20:00", updated = "2019-03-07T01:05:42+00:00", description = "Cyclones lineup change (Nick Weiler-Babb, Lindell Wigginton, Talen Horton-Tucker, Michael Jacobson, Tyrese Haliburton)", 
    event_type = "lineupchange", attribution = structure(list(
        name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
        team_basket = "right"), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "team_basket")), location = structure(list(coord_x = 0L, 
        coord_y = 0L), .Names = c("coord_x", "coord_y")), on_court = structure(list(
        home = structure(list(name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", 
            id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", players = list(
                structure(list(full_name = "Derek Culver", jersey_number = "1", 
                  id = "9b4cdef4-5b76-4981-ad7a-14abbb425677"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jordan McCabe", 
                  jersey_number = "5", id = "a1bfd18b-7d51-4164-942c-8dc73df868bb"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jermaine Haley", 
                  jersey_number = "10", id = "453d63d6-74ce-4169-9405-e0b2444e45f2"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Chase Harler", 
                  jersey_number = "14", id = "8a7e4346-4933-40ab-90f5-017fce37efed"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lamont West", 
                  jersey_number = "15", id = "b191d2a3-19d5-48ed-b4c4-a55b6e039d8d"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", 
        "market", "id", "players")), away = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", 
            market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
            players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Nick Weiler-Babb", 
                jersey_number = "1", id = "067af76a-e3d7-439e-8a8a-b662f3ec08de"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lindell Wigginton", 
                jersey_number = "5", id = "5c09bc24-a9e0-427f-b611-70231a651bdf"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
                jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Michael Jacobson", 
                jersey_number = "12", id = "0ad642b3-b38e-47f7-adac-34039306826f"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Tyrese Haliburton", 
                jersey_number = "22", id = "82cee878-39a7-4fd2-a38f-76be4dd4cea4"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
        "id", "players"))), .Names = c("home", "away"))), .Names = c("id", 
"clock", "updated", "description", "event_type", "attribution", 
"location", "on_court")), structure(list(id = "b7b050c2-21f1-4860-af7b-ec443301ba13", 
    clock = "20:00", updated = "2019-03-07T01:02:20+00:00", description = "Mountaineers lineup change (Derek Culver, Jordan McCabe, Jermaine Haley, Emmitt Matthews Jr., Lamont West)", 
    event_type = "lineupchange", attribution = structure(list(
        name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", 
        team_basket = "left"), .Names = c("name", "market", "id", 
    "team_basket")), location = structure(list(coord_x = 0L, 
        coord_y = 0L), .Names = c("coord_x", "coord_y")), on_court = structure(list(
        home = structure(list(name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", 
            id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", players = list(
                structure(list(full_name = "Derek Culver", jersey_number = "1", 
                  id = "9b4cdef4-5b76-4981-ad7a-14abbb425677"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jordan McCabe", 
                  jersey_number = "5", id = "a1bfd18b-7d51-4164-942c-8dc73df868bb"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jermaine Haley", 
                  jersey_number = "10", id = "453d63d6-74ce-4169-9405-e0b2444e45f2"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Emmitt Matthews Jr.", 
                  jersey_number = "11", id = "70f012ae-5deb-42da-9fff-94ac68ae36a7"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lamont West", 
                  jersey_number = "15", id = "b191d2a3-19d5-48ed-b4c4-a55b6e039d8d"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", 
        "market", "id", "players")), away = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", 
            market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
            players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Nick Weiler-Babb", 
                jersey_number = "1", id = "067af76a-e3d7-439e-8a8a-b662f3ec08de"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lindell Wigginton", 
                jersey_number = "5", id = "5c09bc24-a9e0-427f-b611-70231a651bdf"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
                jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Michael Jacobson", 
                jersey_number = "12", id = "0ad642b3-b38e-47f7-adac-34039306826f"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Tyrese Haliburton", 
                jersey_number = "22", id = "82cee878-39a7-4fd2-a38f-76be4dd4cea4"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
        "id", "players"))), .Names = c("home", "away"))), .Names = c("id", 
"clock", "updated", "description", "event_type", "attribution", 
"location", "on_court")), structure(list(id = "4b748b1e-2f0f-4dbf-9b05-452dce611c7c", 
    clock = "20:00", updated = "2019-03-07T01:02:01+00:00", description = "Open inbound Cyclones", 
    event_type = "openinbound", attribution = structure(list(
        name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
        team_basket = "right"), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "team_basket")), location = structure(list(coord_x = 455L, 
        coord_y = 384L), .Names = c("coord_x", "coord_y")), possession = structure(list(
        name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c"), .Names = c("name", 
    "market", "id")), on_court = structure(list(home = structure(list(
        name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", 
        players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Derek Culver", 
            jersey_number = "1", id = "9b4cdef4-5b76-4981-ad7a-14abbb425677"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jordan McCabe", 
            jersey_number = "5", id = "a1bfd18b-7d51-4164-942c-8dc73df868bb"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jermaine Haley", 
            jersey_number = "10", id = "453d63d6-74ce-4169-9405-e0b2444e45f2"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Emmitt Matthews Jr.", 
            jersey_number = "11", id = "70f012ae-5deb-42da-9fff-94ac68ae36a7"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lamont West", 
            jersey_number = "15", id = "b191d2a3-19d5-48ed-b4c4-a55b6e039d8d"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "players")), away = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", 
        market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
        players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Nick Weiler-Babb", 
            jersey_number = "1", id = "067af76a-e3d7-439e-8a8a-b662f3ec08de"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lindell Wigginton", 
            jersey_number = "5", id = "5c09bc24-a9e0-427f-b611-70231a651bdf"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
            jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Michael Jacobson", 
            jersey_number = "12", id = "0ad642b3-b38e-47f7-adac-34039306826f"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Tyrese Haliburton", 
            jersey_number = "22", id = "82cee878-39a7-4fd2-a38f-76be4dd4cea4"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "players"))), .Names = c("home", "away"))), .Names = c("id", 
"clock", "updated", "description", "event_type", "attribution", 
"location", "possession", "on_court")), structure(list(id = "14d746d7-f213-43be-8023-df69ea1aba60", 
    clock = "19:40", updated = "2019-03-07T01:02:26+00:00", description = "Jermaine Haley misses two point jump shot", 
    event_type = "twopointmiss", attribution = structure(list(
        name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", 
        team_basket = "left"), .Names = c("name", "market", "id", 
    "team_basket")), location = structure(list(coord_x = 160L, 
        coord_y = 390L), .Names = c("coord_x", "coord_y")), on_court = structure(list(
        home = structure(list(name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", 
            id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", players = list(
                structure(list(full_name = "Derek Culver", jersey_number = "1", 
                  id = "9b4cdef4-5b76-4981-ad7a-14abbb425677"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jordan McCabe", 
                  jersey_number = "5", id = "a1bfd18b-7d51-4164-942c-8dc73df868bb"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jermaine Haley", 
                  jersey_number = "10", id = "453d63d6-74ce-4169-9405-e0b2444e45f2"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Emmitt Matthews Jr.", 
                  jersey_number = "11", id = "70f012ae-5deb-42da-9fff-94ac68ae36a7"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lamont West", 
                  jersey_number = "15", id = "b191d2a3-19d5-48ed-b4c4-a55b6e039d8d"), .Names = c("full_name", 
                "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", 
        "market", "id", "players")), away = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", 
            market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
            players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Nick Weiler-Babb", 
                jersey_number = "1", id = "067af76a-e3d7-439e-8a8a-b662f3ec08de"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lindell Wigginton", 
                jersey_number = "5", id = "5c09bc24-a9e0-427f-b611-70231a651bdf"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
                jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Michael Jacobson", 
                jersey_number = "12", id = "0ad642b3-b38e-47f7-adac-34039306826f"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Tyrese Haliburton", 
                jersey_number = "22", id = "82cee878-39a7-4fd2-a38f-76be4dd4cea4"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
        "id", "players"))), .Names = c("home", "away")), statistics = list(
        structure(list(type = "fieldgoal", made = FALSE, shot_type = "jump shot", 
            team = structure(list(name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", 
                id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e"), .Names = c("name", 
            "market", "id")), player = structure(list(full_name = "Jermaine Haley", 
                jersey_number = "10", id = "453d63d6-74ce-4169-9405-e0b2444e45f2"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id"))), .Names = c("type", "made", 
        "shot_type", "team", "player")))), .Names = c("id", "clock", 
"updated", "description", "event_type", "attribution", "location", 
"on_court", "statistics")), structure(list(id = "68ad7e77-8254-4978-bad0-69d5c5c854e8", 
    clock = "19:38", updated = "2019-03-07T01:02:26+00:00", description = "Talen Horton-Tucker defensive rebound", 
    event_type = "rebound", attribution = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", 
        market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
        team_basket = "right"), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "team_basket")), location = structure(list(coord_x = 160L, 
        coord_y = 390L), .Names = c("coord_x", "coord_y")), possession = structure(list(
        name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c"), .Names = c("name", 
    "market", "id")), on_court = structure(list(home = structure(list(
        name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", 
        players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Derek Culver", 
            jersey_number = "1", id = "9b4cdef4-5b76-4981-ad7a-14abbb425677"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jordan McCabe", 
            jersey_number = "5", id = "a1bfd18b-7d51-4164-942c-8dc73df868bb"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jermaine Haley", 
            jersey_number = "10", id = "453d63d6-74ce-4169-9405-e0b2444e45f2"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Emmitt Matthews Jr.", 
            jersey_number = "11", id = "70f012ae-5deb-42da-9fff-94ac68ae36a7"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lamont West", 
            jersey_number = "15", id = "b191d2a3-19d5-48ed-b4c4-a55b6e039d8d"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "players")), away = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", 
        market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
        players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Nick Weiler-Babb", 
            jersey_number = "1", id = "067af76a-e3d7-439e-8a8a-b662f3ec08de"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lindell Wigginton", 
            jersey_number = "5", id = "5c09bc24-a9e0-427f-b611-70231a651bdf"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
            jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Michael Jacobson", 
            jersey_number = "12", id = "0ad642b3-b38e-47f7-adac-34039306826f"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Tyrese Haliburton", 
            jersey_number = "22", id = "82cee878-39a7-4fd2-a38f-76be4dd4cea4"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "players"))), .Names = c("home", "away")), statistics = list(
        structure(list(type = "rebound", rebound_type = "defensive", 
            team = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", 
                id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c"), .Names = c("name", 
            "market", "id")), player = structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
                jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id"))), .Names = c("type", "rebound_type", 
        "team", "player")))), .Names = c("id", "clock", "updated", 
"description", "event_type", "attribution", "location", "possession", 
"on_court", "statistics")), structure(list(id = "d6581039-4c99-49c4-8a9d-f00d70fa484a", 
    clock = "19:28", updated = "2019-03-07T01:02:37+00:00", description = "Talen Horton-Tucker makes three point jump shot (Tyrese Haliburton assists)", 
    event_type = "threepointmade", attribution = structure(list(
        name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
        team_basket = "right"), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "team_basket")), location = structure(list(coord_x = 799L, 
        coord_y = 163L), .Names = c("coord_x", "coord_y")), possession = structure(list(
        name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e"), .Names = c("name", 
    "market", "id")), on_court = structure(list(home = structure(list(
        name = "Mountaineers", market = "West Virginia", id = "f770d3a2-221c-49ce-9c7a-680f7417fe9e", 
        players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Derek Culver", 
            jersey_number = "1", id = "9b4cdef4-5b76-4981-ad7a-14abbb425677"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jordan McCabe", 
            jersey_number = "5", id = "a1bfd18b-7d51-4164-942c-8dc73df868bb"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Jermaine Haley", 
            jersey_number = "10", id = "453d63d6-74ce-4169-9405-e0b2444e45f2"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Emmitt Matthews Jr.", 
            jersey_number = "11", id = "70f012ae-5deb-42da-9fff-94ac68ae36a7"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lamont West", 
            jersey_number = "15", id = "b191d2a3-19d5-48ed-b4c4-a55b6e039d8d"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "players")), away = structure(list(name = "Cyclones", 
        market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c", 
        players = list(structure(list(full_name = "Nick Weiler-Babb", 
            jersey_number = "1", id = "067af76a-e3d7-439e-8a8a-b662f3ec08de"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Lindell Wigginton", 
            jersey_number = "5", id = "5c09bc24-a9e0-427f-b611-70231a651bdf"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
            jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Michael Jacobson", 
            jersey_number = "12", id = "0ad642b3-b38e-47f7-adac-34039306826f"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")), structure(list(full_name = "Tyrese Haliburton", 
            jersey_number = "22", id = "82cee878-39a7-4fd2-a38f-76be4dd4cea4"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id")))), .Names = c("name", "market", 
    "id", "players"))), .Names = c("home", "away")), statistics = list(
        structure(list(type = "fieldgoal", made = TRUE, shot_type = "jump shot", 
            three_point_shot = TRUE, points = 3L, team = structure(list(
                name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c"), .Names = c("name", 
            "market", "id")), player = structure(list(full_name = "Talen Horton-Tucker", 
                jersey_number = "11", id = "7513239c-27a3-455c-a670-167b3f23a071"), .Names = c("full_name", 
            "jersey_number", "id"))), .Names = c("type", "made", 
        "shot_type", "three_point_shot", "points", "team", "player"
        )), structure(list(type = "assist", team = structure(list(
            name = "Cyclones", market = "Iowa State", id = "0e4258fa-3154-4c16-b693-adecab184c6c"), .Names = c("name", 
        "market", "id")), player = structure(list(full_name = "Tyrese Haliburton", 
            jersey_number = "22", id = "82cee878-39a7-4fd2-a38f-76be4dd4cea4"), .Names = c("full_name", 
        "jersey_number", "id"))), .Names = c("type", "team", 
        "player")))), .Names = c("id", "clock", "updated", "description", 
"event_type", "attribution", "location", "possession", "on_court", 
"statistics")))
```

The list is acting a big buggy. Direct copy/paste from stackoverflow into my R console is not working... However, when i post the list into an R script, and run that code chunk, the list is created. Apologies again for the bulky data but it is helpful for reproduction of my problem...

From here its simple. I usually use the following function to unnest any JSONs:

```
my.pbp.df <- my.pbp.data %>%
    purrr::map(unlist) %>%
    purrr::map(t) %>%
    purrr::map(as_tibble) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows() %>%
    readr::type_convert() %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

...however the output is not correct.

What I have noticed is that, while the map(unlist) converts each list item into a character vector, and map(t) converts each list item into a matrix, when I run map(as_tibble), I lose the column names of any items in the matrix that are duplicate names. What I'm left with is a dataframe filled with the following names:

```
> colnames(this.periods.data)
 [1] "id"                                  "clock"                               "updated"                             "description"                        
 [5] "event_type"                          "attribution.name"                    "attribution.market"                  "attribution.id"                     
 [9] "attribution.team_basket"             "location.coord_x"                    "location.coord_y"                    "on_court.home.name"                 
[13] "on_court.home.market"                "on_court.home.id"                    "on_court.home.players.full_name"     "on_court.home.players.jersey_number"
[17] "on_court.home.players.id"            "V18"                                 "V19"                                 "V20"                                
[21] "V21"                                 "V22"                                 "V23"                                 "V24"                                
[25] "V25"                                 "V26"                                 "V27"                                 "V28"                                
[29] "V29"                                 "on_court.away.name"                  "on_court.away.market"                "on_court.away.id"                   
[33] "on_court.away.players.full_name"     "on_court.away.players.jersey_number" "on_court.away.players.id"            "V36"                                
[37] "V37"                                 "V38"                                 "V39"                                 "V40"                                
[41] "V41"                                 "V42"                                 "V43"                                 "V44"                                
[45] "V45"                                 "V46"                                 "V47"                                 "possession.name"                    
[49] "possession.market"                   "possession.id"                       "V30"                                 "V31"                                
[53] "V32"                                 "V48"                                 "V49"                                 "V50"                                
[57] "statistics.type"                     "statistics.made"                     "statistics.shot_type"                "statistics.team.name"               
[61] "statistics.team.market"              "statistics.team.id"                  "statistics.player.full_name"         "statistics.player.jersey_number"    
[65] "statistics.player.id"                "statistics.rebound_type"             "statistics.three_point_shot"         "statistics.points"                  
[69] "V62"                                 "V63"                                 "V64"                                 "V65"                                
[73] "V66"                                 "V67"                                 "V68"
```

All of the `V#` column names should actually have column names. For example, V18 - V29 were renamed as such because they actually had the exact same names as the preior 3 columns `on_court.home.players.full_name, on_court.home.players.jersey_number, on_court.home.players.id`. When map(as_tibble) is run, these names are lost.

In short, is there a better way for me to convert this list/JSON into a dataframe, without losing the column names?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** the desired output is simply a complete set of column names. V18 should be on_court.home.players.full_name.2, V19 should be on_court.home.players.jersey_number.2, V20 should be on_court.home.players.id.2, etc. Rather than being auto-converted into meaningless V18, V19, V20, V21, V22, etc. columns, it would be great if the duplicated column names automatically added `.x, .y` or `.2, .3, .4, etc.` do the names.

Comment: just made an edit on this. the dput is right but buggy. i am working on it. dput works when you (a) copy and paste into an R script, and run that code chunk, but (b) doesnt work when copy / pasted directly into R console. I dont know why

Comment: @Canovice There is copy&paste buffer limit, and your `dput` exceeds that buffer. I can confirm that the `dput` works when `source`ing from a script.

Comment: @Canovice Could you please explicitly include your expected output (at least for part of your data)?

Comment: yes will do now

Comment: Does `bind_rows(map(my.pbp.data, as.data.frame))` do what you want?

Comment: oh my goodness! yes it does oh wow that's great !!!

Comment: @Canovice Great, I wasn't sure whether you actually wanted the `.1`, `.2`, ... suffixed columns.

Comment: @RonakShah Done:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
df <- bind_rows(map(my.pbp.data, as.data.frame))
```

of even more succinctly (thanks to @RonakShah)

```
df <- map_dfr(my.pbp.data, as.data.frame)
```

Inspecting the column names gives

```
colnames(df)
#[1] "id"
#[2] "clock"
#[3] "updated"
#[4] "description"
#[5] "event_type"
#[6] "attribution.name"
#[7] "attribution.market"
#[8] "attribution.id"
#[9] "attribution.team_basket"
#[10] "location.coord_x"
#[11] "location.coord_y"
#[12] "on_court.home.name"
#[13] "on_court.home.market"
#[14] "on_court.home.id"
#[15] "on_court.home.players.full_name"
#[16] "on_court.home.players.jersey_number"
#[17] "on_court.home.players.id"
#[18] "on_court.home.players.full_name.1"
#[19] "on_court.home.players.jersey_number.1"
#[20] "on_court.home.players.id.1"
#[21] "on_court.home.players.full_name.2"
#[22] "on_court.home.players.jersey_number.2"
#[23] "on_court.home.players.id.2"
#[24] "on_court.home.players.full_name.3"
#[25] "on_court.home.players.jersey_number.3"
#[26] "on_court.home.players.id.3"
#[27] "on_court.home.players.full_name.4"
#[28] "on_court.home.players.jersey_number.4"
#[29] "on_court.home.players.id.4"
#[30] "on_court.away.name"
#[31] "on_court.away.market"
#[32] "on_court.away.id"
#[33] "on_court.away.players.full_name"
#[34] "on_court.away.players.jersey_number"
#[35] "on_court.away.players.id"
#[36] "on_court.away.players.full_name.1"
#[37] "on_court.away.players.jersey_number.1"
#[38] "on_court.away.players.id.1"
#[39] "on_court.away.players.full_name.2"
#[40] "on_court.away.players.jersey_number.2"
#[41] "on_court.away.players.id.2"
#[42] "on_court.away.players.full_name.3"
#[43] "on_court.away.players.jersey_number.3"
#[44] "on_court.away.players.id.3"
#[45] "on_court.away.players.full_name.4"
#[46] "on_court.away.players.jersey_number.4"
#[47] "on_court.away.players.id.4"
#[48] "possession.name"
#[49] "possession.market"
#[50] "possession.id"
#[51] "statistics.type"
#[52] "statistics.made"
#[53] "statistics.shot_type"
#[54] "statistics.team.name"
#[55] "statistics.team.market"
#[56] "statistics.team.id"
#[57] "statistics.player.full_name"
#[58] "statistics.player.jersey_number"
#[59] "statistics.player.id"
#[60] "statistics.rebound_type"
#[61] "statistics.three_point_shot"
#[62] "statistics.points"
#[63] "statistics.type.1"
#[64] "statistics.team.name.1"
#[65] "statistics.team.market.1"
#[66] "statistics.team.id.1"
#[67] "statistics.player.full_name.1"
#[68] "statistics.player.jersey_number.1"
#[69] "statistics.player.id.1"
```